# Is there any quick way to switch between docker hub accounts in command line?

Tags: docker

Tired of typing in login and password. So the registry is the same, but accounts are different. Should I just make a script that replaces ~/.docker/config.json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The `config.json` can only hold one credentials value for each remote registry. Moreover, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/docker/kitematic/issues/700) to handle multiple logins to dockerhub.

However, you can easily solve the problem using bash aliases. Edit your `~/.bashrc` file and add the following lines:

```
alias dl1='docker login -u <user1> -p <password1>'
alias dl2='docker login -u <user2> -p <password2>'
```

Now you can do `dl1` to login to account1 and `dl2` to switch to account2

You can basically also do something similar if you are on MAC or Windows.

Comment: I would say that writting the password like this is insecure.

Comment: You can omit the `-p` option and the alias will ask you for the password once you run it. But note that by default docker stores the crdentials in `config.json` base64 encoded which can be easily decoded.

Comment: I ended up copying entire `config.json` files.